# jQuery string concatenation not working with Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, variables, concatenation

In my code I'm trying to concatenate my jQuery variables like this

```
 user_username = $(this).parent().parent().children('td:nth-child(15)').text(); //value is m
```

But this works

```
 $('#photo').attr('src', "{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => 'm.jpg']) }}"); // the image is showing
```

While this doesn't

```
 $('#photo').attr('src', "{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => '"+user_username+".jpg']) }}"); // the image is not showing
```

Note: I'm showing image using laravel

The problem is when I alert my string it return %22+user_username+%22.jpg instead of m.jpg

Comment: What does it mean "not working"?

Comment: `user_username` has value?

Comment: yes the value is m << image name

Comment: Check that img `src` changed to your value.

Comment: again: What does it mean "not working"? Is the value lost? Syntax error? Anything?

Comment: the image is not showing sir

Comment: Maybe `src` of image doesn't change, or your image address is wrong.

Comment: Any errors? Are you sure that `user_username` is a string and not an array of length 1?

Comment: I found my problem when i alert my string it return %22+user_username+%22.jpg instead of m.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Can you do that like this way..

Just replace the line where you attring your src with this.

```
var path = "{{ route('account.image',['filename' => 'example']) }}";

$('#photo').attr('src', path.raplace('example', user_username+'.jpg'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about laravel, but this line is a laravel specific php template tag:

```
{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => '"+user_username+".jpg']) }}
```

So your javascript var isn't part of the route because it's generated by PHP on runtime.

I could be wrong but there is nothing else which could be a reason. So you have to set the filename via laravel or set the filename outside of the route tag.

Edit: Try get the route with an empty filename and concatinate the filename after the laravel tag:

```
$('#photo').attr('src', "{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => '']) }}"+user_username+".jpg");
```

Another solution (change the filename via jQuery):

```
$('#photo').attr('src', "{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => '"+user_username+".jpg']) }}");

var src = $('#photo').attr('src'); 
var path = src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('/'));

$('#photo').attr('src', path + '/' + user_username + '.jpg');
```

Comment: $('#photo').attr('src', "{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => '"+user_username+".jpg']) }}");

Im going to change the src of my img

Comment: Yes, but user_username doesn't exist for the laravel tag.

Comment: I use jquery sir. I found my problem when i alert my string it return %22+user_username+%22.jpg instead of m.jpg

Comment: Please understand that inside the laravel tag, you are on PHP side. So your javascript var `user_username` is a simple string. This also explains why this is parsed to `%22+user_username+%22.jpg`

Comment: hmmm so what can I dor sir? should I convert jquery to php?

Comment: Take a look at my answer above.